# What is the proper way to update react application to resolve vulnerability

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on react application and there are some vulnerability related to **react-script** coming after running **npm audit**. My current **react-script** version is **4.0.3**. I did tried to fix the vulnerability by running **npm install react-scripts@5.0.0**. After running the **npm install react-scripts@5.0.0** in console, there is no vulnerability showing up but my react application started displaying empty page.

Can someone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: While I cannot answer your question, your manual fix helped me with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have breaking changes in your code base. To get your app working again, you will have to fix all the places that broke.

If you don't want to do a complete upgrade `react-scripts` the next best thing is to simply run `npm audit fix` which will try to automatically update the vulnerable packages, that will not cause any braking changes. Simply running `npm update` will also try to update all your packages without causing any braking changes which will also fix lots of vulnerabilities.

But if the audit still shows vulnerability you will have no other option but to update the package manually like what you did, and then deal with the changes.

Comment: I did tried both of the approaches, by running npm audit fix and manually updating the packages and still I'm struck on same point.